# Trigger in Android Studio to undo multiple changes

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to set trigger point in android studio to revert/undo multiple changes from our predefined trigger point. This will be very helpful to test our app for any temporary changes.

Simply saying I added some activities (for which I am unsure) to my app but later (after playing with the code for half an hour so multiple changes done) decided to remove that activities, so how can I switch back to exactly that position? (tried undo but no success).

Information will be useful in future at least.

Comment: Use a VCS like git or mercurial and you can revert to any state that you want.

Comment: any offline solution will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can create an offline repo at anytime with any dvcs (git or mercurial).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can you give me more details about it as I am newbie I am quite confused. What all I need to to create offline repo. Anyway Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with the Local History feature. You can set a label using VCS | Local History | Put Label...

To restore to a label, right-click the root directory of your project in the Project view, select "Local History | Show History..." from the popup menu, scroll down to your label and click the "Revert" button in the toolbar.

(Setting a Git or Mercurial repository, as recommended in the comments, is also a valid option but it's more involved.)